# Stuck in a do while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Hello guys so here is my problem since i was stuck in this block of code for more then 2 day

i want to make my programe monitor a specifique application and wait for it to be lunch i tried the "Do and While loop" but its not working i have checked and rechecked and i couldnt find a solution for this problem

```
        HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name")); 

        do {
        if(hwnd == nullptr ) {            /* if the window has not beign found */
        cout << "window not found!" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
        }
       }while(hwnd == nullptr);

  /*******************************************************************/

 starting the next code once the window of the programe has been found
```

so my problem is  i keep getting ""window not found!" when i launch my own program first and then lunch the program wish i try to monitor , but when i start the program   i wish  to monitor then i launch my own program everything work fine

tnks for your help--- edit Problem sloved

Comment: You don't change hwnd inside the loop so it will never ever end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: Polling is wrong.

If you need to be informed that a certain window is created, use the tool that's specifically tailored for this. Set up a [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) hook (calling [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx)) that listens for [`EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) events. In your [WinEventProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373885.aspx) callback you can filter out the your window of interest, by inspecting it's window title, window class, certain styles (and combinations thereof).

This doesn't waste resources like your attempt to poll every second, and doesn't exhibit the race conditions either (e.g. missing a window because it was created and destroyed in between sampling points).

Comment: i already fixed the problem thx for the feedback , i will try to use WinEvent since its dosent waste lot off resource

Answer (score 4):

You're not changing `hwnd` inside the loop. You need to call `FindWindow()` in the loop. You can use a regular `while` loop instead of `do-while`, so you don't need to do the call twice.

```
while ((hwnd = FindWindow(0, "my programme window name")) == nullptr) {
    cout << "window not found!" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Thx man i just tested and its worked , but the rest of my code didnt get executed feel like i am still stuck in a loop

Comment: While this addresses (and solves) the question that was asked, it merely helps implementing the wrong approach altogether. [Polling is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38141932/1889329).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value of `hwnd` was `nullptr` when it entered the loop; you are not changing its value in the loop.  Since the condition `hwnd == nullptr` is always true, you get an infinite loop.

In order to overcome this issue, you need to change the value of `hwnd` inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your loop changes `hwnd`, so it is impossible to get out of the loop (as you've seen).

You need to make something inside the loop change `hwnd` so that it is possible that (eventually) `hwnd` won't `== nullptr`. e.g. `hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name"));`

I'd refactor to:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name")); 
while(hwnd == nullptr)
{
    cout << "window not found!" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name")); 
}
```

Comment: i just tried this one still not working  , still stuck in a loop for the the first block of the code

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is "FindWindow(0,("my programme window name"))" can't return an available hwnd so the loop is stuck.

Maybe you can try 10 times, if hwnd was still null, break the loop or exit the program.

```
#define MAX_COUNT 10
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name"));
int count = 0; 
while(hwnd == nullptr && count < MAX_COUNT) {
    count++;
    cout << "window not found!" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    hwnd = FindWindow(0,("my programme window name"));
}
```